# iOS - extending two classes in one

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have extended the UIVIewController class with several functions I want.

I want to add the same functions to the UITableViewController class, I mean, to extend that class too.

In order to do that I have to duplicate all the methods on the extended viewController class to a new pair of files that will be used to extend the tableViewController class. Sorry for my ignorance, but there's a way to extend both classes without that redundancy? I mean, to have just one generic extension class (?) that could be inherited by the viewController and tableViewController extension files? Sorry if this is confuse. What I mean is that instead of this:

```
UIViewController+extensions.h
UIViewController+extensions.m
```

both containing a lot of extension methods for the UIViewController class and

```
UITableViewController+extensions.h
UITableViewController+extensions.m
```

both containing a lot of extension methods for the UITableViewController class.

I want this:

```
GenericExtension.h
GenericExtension.m
```

This, containing the extension methods

then,

UIViewController+extension and UITableViewController+extension, both inheriting GenericExtension, so I have just one copy of the extension methods.

Is that possible?

Comment: This is called multiple inheritance. Objective-C doesn't have this.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use inheritance but a category on `UIViewController` (as your file naming suggests), those methods will be available in `UITableViewController` as well. Make sure to import your header file in your `UITableViewController` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Write all your methods in (**GenericExtension.h/.m**) make it of type UIViewController

Later inside `UIViewController`

```
@interface RootViewController : Generic Extensions
```

You can do the same with `UITableViewController` since `UITableViewController` is derived from `UIViewController`.